# Create new Android Notification from app widget in AppWidgetProvider or Service class?

Tags: android, notifications, widget, appwidgetprovider

**Q) Is it possible to create a system notification (that appears in the pull down shade) from an app widget?**

Specifically I want to do this from my:
`RemoteFetchService.class`, that fetches my remote data...
OR
`AppWidgetProvider.class`, that updates the widget UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a notification from a service.
Here's an example code.

```
private void triggerNotification() {
        CharSequence title = "title";
        CharSequence message = "message";
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification;
        notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ico_event, "Notifiy.. ",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, message, pendingIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Have in mind that this is a code I took from my app, so you might need to replace some values to match your app.